# ADC to RAM signal reconstruction (after send it to VGA)

Tags: vhdl, ram, adc, vga

I should reconstruct a wave from the ADC into the RAM and later send it to the VGA.

I wrote this module, but when I synthesize, vivado produces an error:[Synth 8-3380] loop condition does not converge after 2000 iterations.

The error refers to the while loop, but i don't understand the reason. Unfortunately, if I can't synthezise the module i don't understand if it works well.

This is the module:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
--use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx leaf cells in this code.
--library UNISIM;
--use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

entity Data_Elab is
    Generic (
            C: integer := 640;          -- Colonne 640
            R: integer := 480           -- Righe 480
            );
    Port (
        --clk:        in std_logic;
        DRP_Data:   in std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
        DRP_Ready:  in std_logic;
        RAM_addr:   out std_logic_vector(17 downto 0);
        RAM_Data:   out std_logic;
        RAM_en:     out std_logic
        );

end Data_Elab;

architecture Behavioral of Data_Elab is
    signal data_reg: integer range 0 to 2**16;
    --signal flag: std_logic;            
begin
    process(DRP_Ready, DRP_Data)
    begin
        if(DRP_Ready'event and DRP_Ready = '1') then
            data_reg <=  to_integer(unsigned(DRP_Data));
        end if;
    end process;

    process(data_reg)
        variable Cont_W: integer range 0 to C-1 := 0;    -- contatore per spostamento tra colonne
        variable Cont_i: integer range 0 to C   := 1;    -- contatore colonne
        variable Cont_x: integer range 0 to R   := 1;    -- contaore per spostamento tra righe
        variable Cont_R: integer range 0 to R   := 0;    -- contatore righe       
    begin
        if(Cont_i <= C) then
            if( data_reg <= (2**16/R)*Cont_x ) then               
                RAM_addr <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( (C*(R-Cont_x))+Cont_W, RAM_addr'length));
                RAM_en<= '1';
                RAM_Data <= '1';                         -- pixel corrispondente alla forma d'onda (bianchi)
                Cont_W := Cont_W+1;
                Cont_i := Cont_i+1;
                --Cont_R := Cont_R+1;
                --Cont_x := 1;    
                    while Cont_R < R loop
                        RAM_addr <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( (C*(R-Cont_x))+Cont_W, RAM_addr'length));
                        RAM_en<= '1';
                        RAM_Data <= '0';                -- pixel neri
                        Cont_R := Cont_R+1;
                        Cont_x:= Cont_x+1;    
                    end loop;
                Cont_R := 0;
            else
                RAM_addr <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( (C*(R-Cont_x))+Cont_W, RAM_addr'length));
                RAM_en<= '1';
                RAM_Data <= '0';                        -- pixel neri
                Cont_R := Cont_R+1;
                Cont_x:= Cont_x+1;
            end if;
        else
            RAM_en<= '0';
            Cont_W := 0;
            Cont_i := 1;
            Cont_x := 1;
            Cont_R := 0;            
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

The module tries to write the full image from 640*480 pixel in the RAM block, in this way i can read later the values stored in the RAM and send them tothe VGA module.

Thank you.

Comment: You have some data coming in from an ADC. One sample at a time. This will consume some time. Yet you have commented out the `clk` input and are trying to implement this with combinational logic. You need to put the VHDL down for a while and use pencil and paper to design a circuit to implement the behaviour you need (not at gate level, but at block level*). Once you have done that, go back to the VHDL and implement it. That circuit is going to have to be _sequential_; that is, it is going to have to use your `clk` input and it is going to require flip-flops.

Comment: *what do I mean by "block level"? I mean draw a diagram with shift-registers, state-machines, counters, flip-flops, clouds of combinational logic etc. [I mean this kind of thing](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=jVYJXMyJOuua1fAP3Z6d0AY&q=digital+circuit+block+diagram+counter+fsm+shift&oq=digital+circuit+block+diagram+counter+fsm+shift&gs_l=img.3...9063.13429..14667...0.0..0.179.1068.17j1......1....1..gws-wiz-img.A6N-nqMf3mg#imgdii=4nh2Ufrz-QiW0M:&imgrc=ZaL2eeOnNedEmM:) - THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION - it is an example of what I mean by block level.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.@user1155120, you're right, but I wanted to find by myself the solution to the problem of generations and consequent saving of the image on RAM. I am using the ZYBO 7000 board. My idea was to use Xilin XADC, in the UG480 guide (page 73) it is specified how to use it for my case. The DRP_Ready signal comes from the ADC, it is high when the ADC has ready data on its registers.

Comment: My code tried to write all the RAM, in this way so I could then read and send the whole image on the VGA module (which I have already done and tested successfully). I tried it on paper (using as a test an image of only 4 * 4 pixels for simplicity) and it seemed to me that it worked well. Although surely I would have to adjust the timing as the ADC gives a new data every 26 cycles of clk (with clk at 25MHz) and the computing time for each data would probably have been longer. However, if the while loop is not synthesizable I will have to completely modify the block.

Answer (score -3):

I guess the synthesizer is not smart enough to know how many times the **while** loop would run, because it changes in every loop. I would recommend using a **for** loop instead.

```
for Cont_R in 0 to R-1 loop
    RAM_addr <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned( (C*(R-Cont_x))+Cont_W, RAM_addr'length));
    RAM_en<= '1';
    RAM_Data <= '0';                -- pixel neri        
    Cont_x:= Cont_x+1;    
end loop;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

But I need to loop with the value of Cont_R that has at that time.
For example:

for Cont_R in Cont_R to R-1 loop

but this produces another mistake
[Synth 8-561] range expression could not be resolved to a constant